# Section Element not displaying anything and/or has whitespace surrounding it

Tags: html, css

The content does not display at all, or leaves whitespace around the `<section>` element.

This is to do with the `display: inline-block` style that is set by default. So I tried overriding that by setting `display: block;` on all child elements, This led to `<section>` not displaying at all on the site.

So I how do I get this to fall together. And remove the whitespace.

Here is a Snippet:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {
    display: inline-block;
}
html {  
    height: 100vh;
}
body { 
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Main Content Page */

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18vh;
    background-color: orange;
}
aside {
    width: 20%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: orange; 
}
section {
    width: 79%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: darkgrey; 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset; 
}
```

```html
<main id="content">

<header>
 <h1>Just a random Header</h1>
</header>

<aside>
 <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p> 
</aside>

<section>
 <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
 <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
 <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
 <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
</section>

</main>
```

Strangely enough, neither the Snippet or Codepen show this issue, so here is a screenshot to show the issues, both on Firefox and Chrome:

[image: Issue Result]

Comment: why didn't you leave `width:80%` on `section` as in PaulieD's answer to your previous question ?

Comment: Leaving it at 80% meant the <section> did not display at all on the browser, If you look on the comments there is a screenshot showing that, Here it is again: https://i.imgsafe.org/631ba0d94e.png

Comment: oh. that's because of the `inline-block` . it adds additional white-spaces. you could change your HTML so that the aside and section divs, come right one after another like so `</aside><section>` no ' enter ' breaklines or spaces  between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leave `width:80%` on `section` and, because they are `inline-block`s , you should use some 'tricks' to remove the white-spaces between them

for example

1. `</aside><section>` . when `asides` ends, `<section>` starts immediately without breaklines or spaces in HTML
2. `</aside><!--
   --><section>` using comments.
3. you could use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`

Comment: Excellent, I don't like the idea of Option 1, It leaves horrible markup, Option 3 I was thinking about, but it may lead to more issues regarding the flex, Not sure on that though, so i opted for option 2, Using HTML comments, <!--This comment is to help remove the whitespace between these elements :/--> Nice and simple, and if another dev takes over it is self explanatory, Thank you.